# GWT. Can be used Channel API without GAE?

Tags: java, gwt

Channel API it is feature of GAE or feature of GWT? Can I use Channel API with simple GWT RemoteServiceServlet? (my app dont use GAE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel API is a GAE API, so yes you can use it only within the GAE environment. If you are planing to deploy your servlets in GAE, you can still use channel API.

If you are not planning to use GAE as your server, and only use GWT on client/UI side, then you can use other options like Comet (Check link at http://caucho.com/resin-3.1/examples/servlet-comet/ for an example). I am not much aware of other "push" APIs, but some search would give you answers.

Also check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html